# Elmish.Wpf binding for LiveCharts LabelFormatter

Tags: f#, livecharts, elmish-wpf

I am trying to convert the LiveCharts example for a [Basic Line Chart](https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts/tree/master/Examples/Wpf/CartesianChart/BasicLine) to use with Elmish.Wpf

I have bindings for everything except the "YFormatter".  What sort of Binding should I use?

```
type Model = {
   AllSeries: SeriesCollection
   Labels: string[]
   Formatter: ???
}

let init() = (
    AllSeries = 
       let series = new SeriesCollection()
       series.Add(new LineSeries(Title="S1", Values=new ChartVAlues<int>(seq {4; 6; 5})))
       series
    Labels = [| "Jan"; "Feb"; "Mar" |]
    Formatter = ???
}

let bindings () : Binding<Model, MessageType> list = [
    "AllSeries" |> Binding.oneWay(fun m -> m.AllSeries)
    "Labels" |> Binding.oneWay(fun m-> m.Labels)
    "YFormatter" |> ?????
]
```

The xaml is as per the Basic Line Chart example

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding AllSeries}">
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <lvc:Axis Title="Sales" LabelFormatter="{Binding YFormatter}"></lvc:Axis>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:Axis Title="Month" Labels="{Binding Labels}"></lvc:Axis>
     </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
</lvc:CartesianChart>
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work

The Model does not need "Formatter" at all

so, init has nothing to do

bindings has

```
"YFormatter" |> Binding.oneWay(fun m -> Func<Double,_> (fun d -> d.ToString("C")))
```

Comment: Good job answering your own question. I am the lead maintainer of Elmish.WPF. If you have any other questions, feel free to ask them on our GutHub.